# ASP.net Associate session with client/request based on ip

Tags: asp.net, flash, session, upload, swfupload

In one web page we use a flash upload control but becouse a flash bug in the upload event the session is lost as its posted back with a new session.

We have tought of using a table with ip and old session id or a query string with the old session id in order to reassing it in the uploaded event...

Knowing the old session id how can i reassign it to the client? (In C#)

Comment: Do you mean data you are storing in HTTPSession or do you mean the Authentication Session (cookie)?

Comment: Surely knowing the session ID won't help because you will still have lost the data inside of the lost session...?

Comment: In theory the problem is that the client request goes from flash in a way that identifies the client as a new one hence giving it a new session...but the old session wouldnt be deleted (only by the timeout in any case)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the control - how do you tell it where to upload to? does it not allow you to configure any parameters that you could identify the session by? this is probably by design, the control probably doesn't have access to the forms authentication cookie (which is probably a good thing!)

Comment: Its the control which does the postback to the page upon completing the upload. And its not by design as its a bug listed in the adobe bug tracking list... 

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1044
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-419
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-201
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracking the user identity:

URL (a unique token in the query string)? i.e. redirect each visitor to same page with their own token in the URL.

Cookies?

For tracking the associated data:

Perhaps then store this user-specific data in an application-level store (keyed on the user token as above) such as [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) object. Of course you should be concerned about the lifetime of this data and should consider persisting it to disk or to a database instead.

**UPDATE**

[This (from the swfupload project)](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/source/browse/swfupload/trunk/samples/asp.net/Global.asax?r=705) looks suspiciously like a work-around for the issue described here...

Or you could just use that tool instead of your current upload control?...

Comment: The only problem i have is losing the relation between the user and its session becouse the flash bug. I have all the data i need using the asp.net session variables.

Comment: it sounds like the control is making it's own request and has not been built to pass back the authentication cookie. I would look at catching the HTTP request early in the pipeline (an HTTPModule or some handling in Global.asax) and using some data in the query string to manually authenticate the request once you know what user it is.

Comment: Seems like you hit the point...gona test it, if works the check its yours... :)

Comment: There is a problem...the request posted by the flash control omits the query string too... :S 
We are thinking about using Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] + Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] in a hashtable to recover its session id...
But if someone knows a better aproach it would be preferred...

Answer (score 0):

Does not work. The IP may hide many users - remember some people go throuh NAT devices sometimes involuntarily (their ISP enforces it, for example satellite providers), so you may have X users using the same IP.

Comment: And passing the session id in the query string before the upload?

Comment: see my update - it looks like it's something like HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add() or Cookies.Set() with the data you pull out of Request...